# How do I stack two divs on mobile but arrange side-by-side on desktop?

Tags: html, css

I have this set up on desktop with a headline on the left and an image on the right. When I collapse the browser less than 880px, I want the image to be centered underneath the headline.

I am struggling with getting the image centered & underneath the headline.

I am fairly new to html/css so any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o7k5qgne/1/

```
<section class="hero">
      <div class="hero-inner">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor<span class="blue-dot">.</span></h1>
      </div>

      <div class="split split-right">
        <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/undertale-rho/images/5/5f/Placeholder.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20180213155916" alt="working" class="right-image">
      </div>
    </section>

    <div class="clients">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor & sit amet</h2>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
    </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: You could use a library like https://getbootstrap.com/. It would make your life lot easier.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `CSS media Query` to detect where (breakpoint) you want the DIVs to stack. See the example below and adjust as needed.

```css
.myDiv {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: orange;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

/* The block of code below tells the browsers what to do on a screen that has a width of 320px or less */

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  
  .myDiv {
  width: 90%;
  display: block; /* Stops it from floating */
  margin: auto; /* Ensures that it is centered */
  margin-bottom: 25px; /* Space between the stacked elements */
    
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv"></div>
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

[More on CSS Media Query](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

See it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5tcy2Ljo/) in action. Resize the browser to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your css. Here I edited your css just to the once that need to make the image and headline responsive.

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/ss123/a7q834sL/1/][1]
```

Styling like you are expecting can simply be achieved by using *css flex box*. To do that you must first put the content inside a container and make it *display:flex*. Then you can use the flex styling for the content inside the container.
*flex-direction:column* will stack the content over. *flex-direction:row* will put the content in a single row.  *jstify-content:space-venly* will justify the content elements with exactly even spaces between them.

Comment: Thanks @Sachintha, that seems to be a very useful tip!

Comment: [Clickable link for JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ss123/a7q834sL/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track here with the media queries you have in place. I would avoid using the absolute positioning on the image, it will get set exactly where you tell it to and not be very flexible. Centering can be done in several ways like with flex box as others have mentioned, or even just throwing a text-align: center on its' parent element. With your media queries on mobile, be weary of padding or vh/vw that you have in place from desktop, you may not want those still in place when you get to a small screen size; looks like in your example you would want to remove padding and the vh on mobile. Also, to help your CSS be a bit easier to manage I would recommend putting your media queries right inside the class to avoid repeating a lot of code, like so:

```
.hero-inner {
    /* Flexbox Stuff */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

    /* Text styles */
    text-align: left;
    width: 50px;
@media only screen and (max-width: 880px) {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80vw;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

        <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 ">

   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-left">


        <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/undertale-rho/images/5/5f/Placeholder.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20180213155916" alt="working" class="right-image">


   </div> 

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-right">


    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
    </p>

    </div>
     </div>

</body>
</html>
```